# How to apply a function to a list using two lists

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

```
def windChillIndex(windSpeed,temp):
    windSpeedInKmH = windSpeed * 3.6
    WCI = 1.1626*((5.2735*(windSpeedInKmH**0.5))+10.45-(0.2778*windSpeedInKmH))*(30-temp)
    return WCI

windSpeed = []
temp = []
count = 0

while (count<1):
    windSpeed.append(float(raw_input("Enter a wind speed in meters per second.")))
    temp.append(float(raw_input("Enter a temperature.")))
    count += 1

for index1, object in enumerate(windSpeed):
    windSpeed[index1] = windChillIndex(object)

out = []
for object in windSpeed:
    out.append(windChillIndex(object))

print out
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you accurately describe the problem.

Comment: What part of the code pertains to your quesiton?

Comment: for index1, object in enumerate(windSpeed):
    windSpeed[index1] = windChillIndex(object)

Comment: It keeps saying windChillIndex() takes exactly 2 arguements

Comment: `windChillIndex` does in fact take two arguments, `windSpeed` and `temp`. Both times you try calling it you are only passing one argument.

Comment: The map function is built for this. `chill = map(windChillIndex, windSpeed, temp)`. It will call the function with elements from the remaining parameters.

Comment: How would I pass the second arguement? For my assignment I'm supposed to make a program that reads input from the user (weather data: windspeed and temp) and takes that input and calculates the windChillIndex. If you could give me a couple of pointers I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind lol! Accidently put 30 instead of 33 in (30-temp). I've been staring at a computer screen for too long!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to iterate over two lists of wind speed values and temperature values, and produce a new list of wind chill values?

If so, you should use the built-in `zip` function. This will take two lists and iterate over them together, giving you pointers to each value.

```
for w, t in zip(windSpeed, temp):
    out.append(windChillIndex(w, t))
```

Comment: Maybe, but that's a totally separate and unrelated question to the one you posted. If you have a question about that function, you should make a new post targeting that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin for that! `map` will call a function with the items of iterables such as lists. 2 lists go in, one list comes out.

```
def windChillIndex(windSpeed,temp):
    windSpeedInKmH = windSpeed * 3.6
    WCI = 1.1626*((5.2735*(windSpeedInKmH**0.5))+10.45-(0.2778*windSpeedInKmH))*(30-temp)
    return WCI

windSpeed = []
temp = []
count = 0

while (count<1):
    windSpeed.append(float(raw_input("Enter a wind speed in meters per second.")))
    temp.append(float(raw_input("Enter a temperature.")))
    count += 1

out = map(windSpeedIndex, windSpeed, temp)
print out
```